# Multi-Valued Managed Properties as Refiners not working

Tags: search, user-profile-property, refinement-panel

I am facing a problem with multi-value managed properties search in SharePoint 2010. When i am adding a user property(Which is multi value) to a managed property and added a custom refinement the refinements are showing very weirdly It is showing as

1. Math; Geology; English
   Math; English

Instead of

1. Math
2. English

And when I click on the refiner it is showing 0 results even though the count is showing 10. I tried searching in Google and found lot of users are having the same problem but I couldn't find any solution .